# Manage sqlite tables on SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an android app published in Playstore.
I need to add some columns to the existing table. 
When I drop and recreate the table, all data will be lost.

Is there any way to alter the database keeping existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add columns you can use `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN column_definition` without dropping the tables.

Please have a read of [SQL As Understood By SQLite - ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), as there are restrictions. The link also discusses other kinds of schema changes.

e.g. you could have something like :-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion = 1 && newVersion > 1) {
        String alterSQL = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + NEWCOLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT 100";
        db.execSQL(alterSQL);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has some problem.
If I use the alter query, every time user updates, it will get executed (?)
If I remove this query in next release, Those who skipped the last update will not have this column...

Comment: @YesudassMoses you do it properly in onUpgrade (e.g. like example now added)

Comment: Thank you I will check it.

Can I run PRAGMA table_info and add only the columns missing from the result set ? Is it a good idea ?

Comment: Note using DEFAULT VALUE value will populate existing rows

Comment: @YesudassMoses I actually have a complete process for not using onUpgrade based upon classes that create a *pseudo schema* which is compared against the actual (looks at sqlite_master and also pragma's). So yes such a way is feasable. Code is [here](https://github.com/Mike-j-t/Modules)